# Distribution of areas of random slices through a cube

Tags: general-topology

As an applied mineralogist I am always dealing with the stereology of taking measurements on a 2D slice through aggregates of multiple 3D objects, i.e. rock. If I assume the 3D object is a sphere, the distribution of areas of random slices is fairly straight forward. The mean area is (2/3) of the area of a central slice.

However, mineral grains are not usually spherical. I am interested in how I might determine the distribution of areas of randomly oriented slices through a cube. Bear in mind that any random section could be a 3 or 4-sided figure.

I'm not mathematician, so I was looking for help...

Cheers
Gary

Answer (score 1):

Your notion of "random" matters here. In fact, it also matters for the sphere as well. Based on your answer of $2/3$ times the area of the central slice, I assume your model of randomly slicing the sphere involves picking a uniformly random point along a diameter of the sphere, and then slicing through that point, perpendicular to the diameter. But you could imagine other models as well, such as choosing a point uniformly at random inside the sphere, then choosing a normal vector uniformly at random (from all unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$), and slicing through that point, perpendicular to that normal vector. I haven't calculated the average cross section area in this case, but I imagine it could be different. [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) deals with a similar question but for random chords on a circle. Different notions of what is meant by a "random chord" lead to three different answers regarding its length.

In any case, you need to specify precisely the distribution of slices through the cube in order to say anything about the distribution of cross sectional areas.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I used the word "random" because when we slice a rock to make a section for microscopic examination, it's generally done randomly, unless an obvious fabric is present, in which case we try to section perependicular to the fabric. Similarly, if we model mineral grains as cubes, the section slice could be at any orientation. I'd like to know how the distribution of "random" section areas compares to the orthogonal section area.

Comment: @Rock_doctor My point is that there is no notion of a "random cross section" without being more specific about the distribution of the slicing plane. For instance, if the slicing plane is more likely to go through points close to the center of the cube than the edge of the cube, that will affect the distribution of the cross section area.

Comment: You say any orientation is possible, but are any more likely than others? Even if we know the distribution of orientations, the location of the slicing plane will affect the answer.